# Setting cookie fails in background html when called on startup

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set a custom cookie in my chrome extension so that my server knows the client is running the extension.

I have been trying this approach:

```
chrome.cookies.set({
   url: 'http://www.mydomain.com',
   name: 'iamalive',
   value: 'yes'
}, function(cookie) { ... });
```

This works perfectly when chrome is already loaded and running(for example: right after installation). but when this code runs while chrome is starting up, i am getting this error:

> Error during cookies.set: No accessible cookie store found for the current execution context.

Is there any way to tell when chrome.cookies API is ready?
If not, is there another solution to the problem, such as modifying the user-agent or adding a custom header to all http requests to the server?

Comment: Where are you executing your code? In a background page? Can you have a five second delay on startup and then set the cookie?

Comment: yes, background page. I can use a delay solution, but if one of the pages opened on startup is on my server, it will think the client is not running the extension. something else i found out: this only happens in a Packaged extension

Comment: @karnyj - did you ever find a solution to this issue (other than a delay)? Or a solution to the not running extension issue?

Comment: @laurencer Did you ever find a solution to this issue? Or get response from karnyj somehow?

Comment: @karnyj It happened to me with no packaged extension as well.