# Chrome extension, Can't get cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get cookies from my Chrome extension when the app is loading:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({ "url": config.cookie.cookieUrl }, function (cookies) {
            if (callback) callback(cookies);
        });
```

Sometimes I get the error:

> Error during cookies.getAll: No accessible cookie store found for the
>   current execution context.

These posts didn't help me:

1. [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296859/setting-cookie-fails-in-background-html-when-called-on-startup)
2. [Google discussion](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113994)

Comment: So the issue happens only during the first seconds when Chrome is starting up?

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon this issue as well and it looks like it's far from being resolved by the chromium project:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113994

The solution I found to work is checking first if there's a cookie store available:

```
    function isCookieStoreAvailable() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores(function (cookieStores) {                
                if (cookieStores.length) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Then retrying several times until it becomes available.

Another thing I did was to reload the extension after 10 seconds of retrying but that's only as a last resort:

`chrome.runtime.reload()`

Hope this helps.